# angular2 how to make a div appear beside after click another div

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I want to make a another page appear after click on div like picture below:

**Before Click:**

[image]

**After Click:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a new component appear:

In your template html add a button. And add  where you want you component to appear.

```
<h1>Billing<a (click)="newBilling()"></a></h1>
<div class="col-xs-6">
     <app-billing-list *ngFor="let billingEl of billings; let i = index" 
     [billing]="billingEl" [index]="i">
     </app-billing-list>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In your Component TS file add a function (In my example newBilling()). This new function will allow to manipulate any data and furthermore will help you to navigate to another URL (in my case from http://localhost:3000/billing to http://localhost:3000/billing/new)

`newBilling() {
    this.router.navigate(['new'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }`

Then in your app-routing module add a path as below. 'new' is a children of 'billing'. billing/new will load a new component ( here BillingEditComponent).

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
path: 'billing', component: BillingComponent, children: [
    { path: 'new', component: BillingEditComponent },
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do:

## Show / Hide Divs

This part is easy and the core of the question. You can simply use an ngif : https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

## CSS Layout

Will depened on the nature of the current CSS but have a look at CSS Flexbox or just google two column layouts